# How to fix send POST request as API fetch on Dev tool without error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

After copy fetch request and send POST request as pasted fetch on Dev Tools, after one minute API fetch is expired and 403 error is appear as below:

[image]

Is there any solution to fix it and send POST request via console?

I need to send some POST request normally through console.

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're correctly sending the fetch requests from the console. The server is rejecting the requests because there's some problem with the data. Without knowing the API, it's impossible to tell why. But it would be a good idea to use `JSON.stringify()` rather than trying to post the JSON as a literal string.